# Pivot table and set analysis in QLik Sense

Tags: qliksense

I'm new to Qlik sense and I have this problem:
I have a pivot table which has a temporal dimension on the rows, let's say "quarters", which can assume the values Q_1,Q_2,Q_3. There are various measures on the columns, for instance let's say there are two measures which contain respectively the volumes of "sold items" and the volumes of "orders", and I want to aggregate these volumes by quarters using the selling date for "sold items" and the order date for "orders". To be more specific, on the cell corresponding to (Q_1, sold_items) for instance, I want to see the volumes of items whose selling date is in Q_1 (Suppose I have the selling date as quarters, I'm not interested in the problem of computing the quarter starting from a date).
Suppose that the dimension of the quarters is not associated to the table of the orders and sold items, so that the items are not automatically assigned to the quarters.
I want to do something like:

```
"sold items" := sum({<[selling date] = '?'>}items) 
"orders" := sum({<[order date] = '?'>}items)
```

Is there a way to do this?
Does it make sense to do something like this:

```
  sum({<[selling date]=quarters >}items)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is that you have several Date fields that you need to represent in the same chart. For that I would suggest to create a 'Canonical Calendar' which joins all those Dates in one column. See [this post](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Design-Blog/Canonical-Date/ba-p/1463578) in qlik community, everything is explained in detail.